# Geometric meaning of the value of an indefinite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I interpret indefinite integrals in term of area? I'm looking at the second fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm dx = F(b) - F(a)$$

What is the meaning of F(b)? Does F(b) mean the area from -infinity to b? If that's the case I can see how $F(b) - F(a)$ is the area from a to b, but it's not clear to me how the indefinite integral evaluated at b can be interpreted as that.

Comment: The function $F$ is any function such that $F'(x)=f(x)$, $x\in (a,b)$.

Comment: $F(q)$ means the area from ANY PARTICULAR point to $q$.  It doesn't matter which point, as long as it is the same for all usages.  That's what allows $F(b) - F(a)$ to work.

Answer (score 0):

In your equation $F$ is not an indefinite integral. It is some particular one of the functions whose derivative is $f$.  Formally speaking, the "indefinite integral" is the set of those functions. There is no such thing as $F(b)$ for an indefinite integral.

Any two of those functions differ by a constant. Geometrically, you can think of their graphs as vertical translations of any one of them.

Comment: I'm asking more how to interpret based on area, but I think johnnyb's answer makes sense. Also, every source I see says that "F" is an indefinite integral